# howto interprete error message

Tags: java, android, stack-trace

I got an stacktrace from my android activity as follow:

```
(TextViewerActivity.java:5460)
```

but my TextViewerActivity.java has only 3200 lines.

Howto interprete this message ? (I never got an linenumber, which doesn't exist)

Comment: `has only 3200 lines` are you serious?  You need to do some refactoring and use a few OOP principles.

Comment: this actually happens when there is crash in the Class itself... suppose i have TextView which itself is a class and have code lines then if im setting text in it using setText and i pass a null value then it will crash in the TextView class.... so to trace the error you need to see the below lines and see for the first line from top of the whole message of your app this is the part where crash happened ... infact you can know the flow from which line the code is going ( i use this "error injection" to know the flow sometimes :) )

hope this helps u :)

Comment: Are you looking at the same code that is executed at runtime? For example if you are using a decompiled version then there could be a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all comments so far. No I am using my own code. Its not decimpiled. I got the Stacktrace in the GoogleDeveloper Conolse under Crashes and ANR's. And I have the same Version running.